# Rasterio does not merge correctly

Tags: merge, rasterio, sentinel-2, sentinelsat

I downloaded some Sentinel-2 data by using python sentinelsat library. Then I grouped the tiles and processed same tiles due to obtain one tile for each groups. To merge these tiles I used rasterio.merge.merge function. However, it produce wrong result. What I got is like below

[image]

I draw some lines and numbered them. Number one should be in place of number two. However, number two is epmty. The resource is below, file names indicate tile names. I use these codes to merge them:

```
import os
import shapely.Geometry
import rasterio
import rasterio.merge
import rasterio.warp
import rasterio.mask

file_path = [f for f in os.listdir(self.SAVE_FOLDER)]
        file_path.sort()
        #file_path.reverse()
        raster_list = [rasterio.open(os.path.join(self.SAVE_FOLDER, f),mode='r',driver="GTiff") for f in file_path]
        
        self.geometry = {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                43.552852,
                38.724315
              ],
              [
                43.552852,
                36.614646
              ],
              [
                37.81111,
                36.614646
              ],
              [
                37.81111,
                38.724315
              ],
              [
                43.552852,
                38.724315
              ]
            ]
          ]
        }
        bounds = shapely.geometry.Polygon(self.geometry["coordinates"][0])
        bounds = rasterio.warp.transform_geom(
                rasterio.crs.CRS.from_epsg(4326),
                raster_list[0].crs,
                bounds
            )
        bounds = shapely.geometry.Polygon(bounds["coordinates"][0]).bounds
        #print(bounds)
        merged_data, out_trans = rasterio.merge.merge(raster_list, bounds =bounds)
        #merged_data, transformed = rasterio.mask.mask(merged_data, bounds, crop=True)
        
        
        merged_meta = raster_list[0].meta.copy()
        merged_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                            "height": merged_data.shape[1],
                            "width": merged_data.shape[2],
                            "transform": out_trans,
                            "crs": raster_list[0].crs,
                            "count": 1,
                            "compress":"lzw"})
        year = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y")
        month = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%m")
        os.makedirs(os.path.join("images",year), exist_ok=True)
        with rasterio.open(os.path.join("images",year,month + ".tif"), mode="w", **merged_meta) as dest:
            dest.write(merged_data)
```

if I reverse raster_files, it happens for number two.

[image]

### Update 1

This problem occurs for just T38 tiles. T38 tiles should be at right side of the image. However, it is at left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Problem is related coordinate system. As they are not in same coordinate system, they overlap. That is why, we first make a coordinate conversion.  I added revised code.

Note: when I made search about coordinate conversion, I saw they make it like below:

```
dst_crs = 'epsg:3857'
raster = rasterio.open('filename.tiff','r')
transform, width, height = rasterio.warp.calculate_default_transform(
    raster.crs, dst_crs, raster.width, raster.height, *raster.bounds)
src_image = raster.read()
dest_im = numpy.zeros_like(src_image)
rasterio.warp.reproject(
            source=src_image,
            destination=dest_im,
            src_transform=raster.transform,
            src_crs=raster.crs,
            dst_transform=transform,
            dst_crs=dst_crs,
            resampling=rasterio.enums.Resampling.nearest,
            num_threads=16)
raster.meta.update({'width': tmp_image.shape[2],
                     'height': tmp_image.shape[1],
                     'crs': dst_crs,
                     'transform': transform,
                     'compress': 'lzw'})
with rasterio.open("out.tif"), mode="w", **raster.meta) as dest:
    dest.write(dest_im)
```

however, it does not work. Do it like:

```
dst_crs = 'epsg:3857'
raster = rasterio.open('filename.tiff','r')
transform, width, height = rasterio.warp.calculate_default_transform(
    raster.crs, dst_crs, raster.width, raster.height, *raster.bounds)
src_image = raster.read()
image, transform_tmp = rasterio.warp.reproject(
            source=src_image,
            destination=numpy.zeros_like(src_image),
            src_transform=raster.transform,
            src_crs=raster.crs,
            dst_transform=transform,
            dst_crs=dst_crs,
            resampling=rasterio.enums.Resampling.nearest,
            num_threads=16)
meta = raster.meta
meta.update({'width': tmp_image.shape[2],
                     'height': tmp_image.shape[1],
                     'crs': dst_crs,
                     'transform': transform_tmp,
                     'compress': 'lzw'})
with rasterio.open("out.tif"), mode="w", **raster.meta) as dest:
    dest.write(image)
```

Here the revised code:

```
import os
import shapely.Geometry
import rasterio
import rasterio.merge
import rasterio.warp
import rasterio.mask

file_path = [f for f in os.listdir(self.SAVE_FOLDER)]
file_path.sort()
raster_list = []
dst_crs = 'epsg:3857'
for file in file_path:
    raster = rasterio.open(os.path.join(self.SAVE_FOLDER,file))
    transform, width, height = rasterio.warp.calculate_default_transform(
    raster.crs, dst_crs, raster.width, raster.height, *raster.bounds)
    src_image = raster.read()
        tmp_image, tmp_transform = rasterio.warp.reproject(
            source=src_image,
            destination=numpy.zeros_like(src_image),
            src_transform=raster.transform,
            src_crs=raster.crs,
            dst_transform=transform,
            dst_crs=dst_crs,
            resampling=rasterio.enums.Resampling.nearest,
            num_threads=16)
        meta = raster.meta
        meta.update({'width': tmp_image.shape[2],
                     'height': tmp_image.shape[1],
                     'crs': dst_crs,
                     'transform': tmp_transform,
                     'compress': 'lzw'})
        tmp_file = rasterio.MemoryFile().open(**meta)
        tmp_file.write(tmp_image)
        raster_list.append(tmp_file)

self.geometry = {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
    [
        [
        43.552852,
        38.724315
        ],
        [
        43.552852,
        36.614646
        ],
        [
        37.81111,
        36.614646
        ],
        [
        37.81111,
        38.724315
        ],
        [
        43.552852,
        38.724315
        ]
    ]
    ]
}
bounds = shapely.geometry.Polygon(self.geometry["coordinates"][0])
bounds = rasterio.warp.transform_geom(
        rasterio.crs.CRS.from_epsg(4326),
        raster_list[0].crs,
        bounds
    )
bounds = shapely.geometry.Polygon(bounds["coordinates"][0]).bounds

merged_data, out_trans = rasterio.merge.merge(raster_list, bounds =bounds)

merged_meta = raster_list[0].meta.copy()
merged_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                    "height": merged_data.shape[1],
                    "width": merged_data.shape[2],
                    "transform": out_trans,
                    "crs": raster_list[0].crs,
                    "count": 1,
                    "compress":"lzw"})
year = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y")
month = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%m")
os.makedirs(os.path.join("images",year), exist_ok=True)
with rasterio.open(os.path.join("images",year,month + ".tif"), mode="w", **merged_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(merged_data)
```