# Gaps between tiles after merging

Tags: merge, rasterio, sentinel-2, copernicus, sentinelsat

I have some TIFF tiles that belongs to Sentinel 2. I downloaded them by using Sentinelsat library. Their coordinates system is mixed; that is why I need to reproject them for a common coordinate system. Then I reprojected them into EPSG 4326. However, after conversion and merging them, some gaps occur between tiles. Here the gaps, it is mid of the image as vertical. It is a part of the image. However, it occurs for the whole image.

[image]

Here my code to reproject and merge the tiles:

```
SAVE_FOLDER = "result"
file_path = [f for f in os.listdir(SAVE_FOLDER)]
raster_list= []
for file in file_path:
            
    raster = rasterio.open(os.path.join(SAVE_FOLDER, file), mode = "r+", driver = "GTiff")
    transform, width, height = rasterio.warp.calculate_default_transform(raster.crs, rasterio.crs.CRS.from_epsg("4326"), raster.width, raster.height, *raster.bounds)
    memfile = rasterio.MemoryFile()
    rst = memfile.open(**raster.meta)
    
tmp_image, tmp_transform = rasterio.warp.reproject(
                source=raster.read(),
                destination=rst.read(),
                src_transform=raster.transform,
                src_crs=raster.crs,
                dst_transform=transform,
                dst_crs=rasterio.crs.CRS.from_epsg("4326"),
                resampling=rasterio.enums.Resampling.nearest)
    rst.write(tmp_image)    
    rst.crs = {"init":"EPSG:4326"} 
    raster_list.append(rst)

      
merged_data, out_trans = rasterio.merge.merge(raster_list)
merged_meta = raster_list[0].meta.copy()
merged_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                            "height": merged_data.shape[1],
                            "width": merged_data.shape[2],
                            "transform": out_trans,
                            "crs": raster_list[0].crs,
                            "count": 1,
                            "compress":"lzw"})
year = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y")
month = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%m")
os.makedirs(os.path.join("images",year), exist_ok=True)
with rasterio.open(os.path.join("images",year,month + ".tif"), mode="w", **merged_meta) as dest:
dest.write(merged_data)
```

#### update 1

Here the whole image. I dotted problamatic sides by red pencil

[image]

Here the list of tiles:

[image]

image names indicate tile name.

#### Update 2

If I pass nodata value to merge and reproject function, I get this image:

[image]

Here the updated code.

```
SAVE_FOLDER = "result"
file_path = [f for f in os.listdir(SAVE_FOLDER)]
raster_list= []
for file in file_path:
            
    raster = rasterio.open(os.path.join(SAVE_FOLDER, file), mode = "r+", driver = "GTiff")
    transform, width, height = rasterio.warp.calculate_default_transform(raster.crs, rasterio.crs.CRS.from_epsg("4326"), raster.width, raster.height, *raster.bounds)
            
    tmp_image, tmp_transform = rasterio.warp.reproject(
                source=raster.read(),
                destination=raster.read(),
                src_transform=raster.transform,
                src_crs=raster.crs,
                dst_nodata = 255
                dst_transform=transform,
                dst_crs=rasterio.crs.CRS.from_epsg("4326"),
                resampling=rasterio.enums.Resampling.nearest)
    raster.write(tmp_image)    
    raster.crs = {"init":"EPSG:4326"} 
    raster_list.append(raster)

      
merged_data, out_trans = rasterio.merge.merge(raster_list, method = 'max', nodata = 255)
merged_meta = raster_list[0].meta.copy()
merged_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                            "height": merged_data.shape[1],
                            "width": merged_data.shape[2],
                            "transform": out_trans,
                            "crs": raster_list[0].crs,
                            "count": 1,
                            "compress":"lzw"})
year = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y")
month = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%m")
os.makedirs(os.path.join("images",year), exist_ok=True)
with rasterio.open(os.path.join("images",year,month + ".tif"), mode="w", **merged_meta) as dest:
dest.write(merged_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass either the nodata or another method than `method='first'` (i.e. max) to [`rasterio.merge.merge`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.merge.html#rasterio.merge.merge).

Here the nodata of the first image overlaps the valid pixels of the second.

Comment: it is already provided as default. However, I checked it and it is same.

Comment: it happens for just vertical. Think the image has 4 tile, this problem occurs as vertical not horizontal.

Comment: Did you try with setting a nodata value ? And not, the default value is `first`, you need to set `max` :)

Comment: I set it as but it was same. I do not thnik it is about nodata value beacause If I do not use coordinate transform to epsg 4326, all tiles are merged correctly except one different utm zone. That is why I have one different utm zone, I have to use coordinate system conversion.

Comment: Yes but you are not setting nodata when reprojecting (and you will have nodata), so when using merge with first method there will be automatically a problem

Comment: What can be done to not have nodata? Is it possible to merge zone 37 and zone 38 without coordinate conversion?

Comment: You are reprojecting a raster from UTM to WGS84. This cannot be done without making your rasters not square, so nodata will be added on the border. However, in rasterio.warp.reproject you didn't specified a nodata value, so the border of your rasters will be set to 0. After that, in merge, you don't add that nodata is 0, so the border of your first raster is kept, and the values which are kept is nodata

Comment: why does it not occur for horizontal ?

Comment: I think this may come from the fact that all the S2 tiles have the same UTM CRS vertically, so the reprojection is coherent among them.
However I would love to see a bigger part of your mosaic (is it classified ?)

And did you test my suggestions ? I persist to think it may help you

Comment: Of course I tried what you said, I set method to 'max' but result was same. I added the whole image and tiles with their names. This problem does not occur for sentinel-hub. However, I need get them from their source by sentinelsat. What do you mean by 'is it classified' ? Many thanks for you helps.

Comment: Ok for the max, but did you set the nodata ? What are the format of the images coming from sentinel-hub ?

Comment: actually nodata would not help me becaues I need these pixels. They are tiff, my files are tiff as wel. This problem occurs after coordinate conversion. However, If I do not apply coordinate conversion, this (problem)[https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/449739/215633] occurs.

Comment: Sentinel-2 tiles overlap themselves. So under the nodata of the first tile you have valid data of another

Comment: Thank you for your all helps. What can we do for this problem ?

Comment: In my opinion you just have to specify the nodata value in reproject and merge and it should solve it. What is the black value that is problematic ?

Comment: Actually if you remove black pixels from there, two side exactly fit.

Comment: Yes, thios is what I expectedc haha Those black pixels are nodata! So you have to set nodata to this value in the two functions (`dst_nodata` in reproject and `nodata` in merge)

Comment: You mean I should give a value for dst_nodata and nodata ?

Comment: Yes, I think this will solve it (pass the value of the black pixels)

Comment: I did what you said and added result to update 2. However, this image is not acceptable for me.

Comment: This is very weird... Could you add the code you wrote in this update ?

Comment: I added it as update

Comment: I saw you added this in the comment section in rasterio. You have other suggestions there, and as they said, you cannot rewrite in the same raster for reproject. I think you should change that.

Comment: actually it is changed in my original code however, I did not change it here to not confuse you. Now i changed it as well.